# What could cause NoReverseMatch error

Tags: django, django-urls

What could cause `NoReverseMatch` error if there is no mistakes in urls.py and template?

Take a look at urls.py:

website.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
urlpatterns = patterns('',

        url(r'^$','base.views.index', name='index'), # works fine
        (r'^accounts/$', include('auth.urls')),
)
```

auth.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from auth.views import accounts

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$' ,accounts, name='accounts'), #not working
)
```

Template with tag `{% url accounts %}` gives me an NoReverseMatch error. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `$` from here:

```
(r'^accounts/$', include('auth.urls')),
```

`$` means end of the line, which is not your case.